# Return JSON from MongoDb without $date

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, json.net

I am using MongoDb with C# in a WebApi app. My data does not lend well to mapped data types due to the dynamic nature of the document stored. For example, here is an example of some data. Note the `Data` section with values that can either be arrays or a single string (`Technician`):

```
{
    "_id" : "5a59129d16d5c42f7444b83d",
    "CreatedDate" : "2018-01-09T20:30:19.455Z",
    "Data" : {
        "AlcoholTest" : [ 
            {
                "Technician" : [ 
                    "STT", 
                    "BAT"
                ],
                "TestReason" : "not well"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I attempt to return the data like above, I get this instead:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a59129d16d5c42f7444b83d"
    },
    "CreatedDate": {
        "$date": 1515529819455
    },
    "Data": {
        "AlcoholTest": [
            {
                "Technician": [
                    "STT",
                    "BAT"
                ],
                "TestReason": "drunk"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public object FindById(string id)
{
    var filter = new BsonDocument { { "_id", ObjectId.Parse(id) } };
    var result = _collection2.Find(filter);
    var note = result.Any() ? result.First() : null;
    var json = note.ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings{OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict});
    return JObject.Parse(json);
}
```

I can't just return the `note` object since Newtonsoft does not know how to convert those `$data` and `$oid` into valid types and returns a parsing error.

When I attempted to use MongoDb mapping classes in .NET, this is what my class looked like (I'm not including the `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap` stuff for simplicity):

```
public class Note
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, IList<IDictionary<string, object>>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried this code, the Newtonsoft did not know how to handle the case where the `object` in `IList<IDictionary<string, object>>` could be an array or string and saved some rather nasty `JArray` and `JObject` data instead.

So here are my questions:

- Is there a way to make the above C# code return identical JSON as what is represented in the Mongo database (or what the UI is sending and expecting to get back)?
- Or is there a way to map my `Data` document using .NET types that would allow me to use MongoDb mapping classes that accepts either string values, arrays, or both?

Comment: remember that a MongoDB document, the object Id [already has the creation date](https://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/)... no need to add that field again

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a different approach for save vs get. For saving, I converted a generic object to BsonDocument, and saved it as it. This resulted in the data format I was expecting (first data format my above question).

I used a strongly-typed collection to get data from the MongoDB so I could avoid the second data format from my question above. To get the data returned in the correct format, I changed this property from

```
public IDictionary<string, IList<IDictionary<string, IList<string>>>> Data { get; set; }
```

to

```
public IDictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
```

This gave me the correctly formatted data I needed. Having two MongoDb collections for getting vs saving was not ideal, but it eliminated my original hack to parse the dictionary BsonDocument into my strongly-typed POCO.